# ¿Existe una forma de enviar parámetros a query de un cursor en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Actualmente desarrollé esta query con el fin de poder controlar las PK de mis tablas referenciales, para poder obtener los id disponibles. Pero tengo el siguiente problema: no puedo enviar parámetros **(xCOLUMNA, xTABLA, xVALOR_DESDE)** a la consulta perteneciente al **CURSOR**.
¿Existe alguna alternativa a lo que estoy planteando?

```
 BEGIN
     DECLARE V_CODIGO INT;
     DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
     DECLARE V_CONTADOR INT DEFAULT 1;

     DECLARE CURSOR_CODIGO CURSOR FOR 
     (SELECT xCOLUMNA FROM xTABLA WHERE xCOLUMNA >= xVALOR_DESDE ORDER BY 1);

     DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


     OPEN CURSOR_CODIGO;
     bucle: LOOP
     FETCH CURSOR_CODIGO INTO V_CODIGO;

     IF V_CODIGO > V_CONTADOR THEN
         LEAVE bucle;
     ELSEIF V_CODIGO < V_CONTADOR THEN
         SET done = TRUE;
     ELSE
         SET V_CONTADOR = V_CONTADOR + 1;
     END IF;

     END LOOP;
     CLOSE CURSOR_CODIGO;
 RETURN V_CONTADOR;
 END;
```

Comment: Es posible enviar `xVALOR_DESDE` como parámetro al cursor, pero `xCOLUMNA` y `xTABLA` actualmente en MySQL no lo veo factible, al menos, de forma nativa o sencilla. Existen algunas alternativas con tablas temporales o vistas (con sus pros y contras) por medio de consultas dinámicas, pero no sería posible desde una función (`FUNCTION`) tendría que cambiar a un procedimiento almacenado (`STORED PROCEDURE`).

Comment: ¿Ids disponibles? ¿Por qué no usar [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)?